# how to uninstall doxygen using make file on Ubuntu (12.04)?

Tags: doxygen

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I have installed doxygen 1.8.3.1 using make install.
I would like to uninstall the doxygen built by make, but I don't find any way to do it using make (uninstall or clean...).
In the Makefile there is no reference to uninstall it the software. :(
Unfortunately I can't use the sudo apt-get remove doxygen because it wasn't an installed. :(
I don't find anything related on the internet. 
Can anyone help me, please?

Thank you in advance,
Fabiola

Answer (score 1):

There is no "uninstall" target. You need to do a "rm" be hand. If you used the standard prefix path "/usr/local" then

```
rm /usr/local/bin/doxygen
rm /usr/local/man/man.1/doxygen.1
```

(more if you install the docs are wizard). Depend on the user used for install, you need sudo to do it.

Comment: I suggest using `locate doxygen` to ensure there are no more artifacts needing removal.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but since it is the first result in google I would like to share another way of uninstalling Doxygen built from source. In the build directory where you've ran `make` there should by a file name `install_manifest.txt`. That file contains paths to files that were installed using `make install` command. All you need to do is to run the following command:

```
sudo xargs rm < install_manifest.txt
```

Of course this assumes that you've kept the build directory or at least the `install_manifest.txt` file. If not you need to remove the files by hand as somebody already suggested.